# it looks like this link is unsecure - Facebook

Tags: wordpress, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I started a new website Alphasix.ca and have been having troubles with posting on Facebook.

I am getting an error that says:

*"It looks like this link is unsecure: alphasix.ca
To protect your account, we recommend not posting the link. If you want to share it anyway, you'll need to complete this security check."*

I then need to fill out a captcha, and then it posts.

The problem is that once I post it, and someone decides to share it - they then are also prompted with the message and need to enter a captcha.

I went in to the debugger settings of Facebook (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/?q=http%3A%2F%2Falphasix.ca)

and fixed the OpenGraph issues by configuring Yoast SEO on my website, and creating a Facebook API, but the problem still persists.

It's now giving me an error saying the image can't be downloaded, yet they are displayed at first try there is no problem accessing them, viewing them quickly, or with their file size. I'm not sure if this may be related to this or not.

I've tried searching in multiple places the phrase:

"This link is unsecure"

but have not been able to come up with anything matching those exact words. I did see people with similar problems, but the wording was slightly different.

Facebooks batch invalidator is reporting no problems.

I ran vulnerability scans on the website, and they came up with nothing. I  also ran blacklist scans and the came up with nothing.

I have also tried to remove WP Super Cache from my website, thinking maybe it was a caching issue.

This is a new website and domain - Hosted on Google Cloud.

I have spent about 20 hours on this so far, and am no closer to finding a solution.

Any help is appreciated.

UPDATE: in an attempt to have someone else run through the captcha, I had my girlfriend share a post and it worked perfectly fine through the Facebook app. I tried again through my account and no luck. I then tried through a secondary I have for managing pages, and it wouldn't share on their either.

UPDATE 2: I just downloaded the Facebook app and it works fine sharing on there. It seems to be a problem only when using a browser or the mobile website.

Comment: Facebook takes a skeptical view of brand-new sites, and stuff like "paying off debt fast" and "formula of success" may be flagging it as well. If enough people do the captcha Facebook will typically consider that in their algorithm as a sign it may be legitimate. To my knowledge, there's not much you can do except wait.

Comment: I just added a couple updates to the original post. It seems to only be an issue when using the Facebook website. The problem doesn't happen on the Facebook phone app.

Comment: Same happens for me where the Android Apps (Messenger and Facebook) work just fine though website (mobile or desktop) gets rejected as "insecure". Not sure how to specifically resolve this (trying the global.sitesafety.trendmicro.com recommendation below).

Strange thing is there is no flagging of insecure content or missing OpenGraph API data in the Sharing Debugger Tool from Facebook themselves.

Comment: I now have my site as reporting as "safe" in TrendMicro, but FB still blocks sending the link via the website. Going to wait a few hours to see if there is potentially a server side cache that is blocking it.

Comment: UPDATE ~3hr later ... no change, still blocked

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that worked for me.
You need to set your website as safe on Trend Micro which Facebook uses.
The link is really hidden, but it is here https://global.sitesafety.trendmicro.com/

You put your link it will say it is unchecked and they will do a check, but after this you go on Reclasify Request button, then Proceed to URL for Home users, check the box saf. I pressed I own this webiste, give a short message that I own the website, my email address and OK.
That was it, I received an email and after that the link could be used on facebook post.

Attenstion tough, you need to put not only the domain, as in [www.x.com](http://www.x.com), but the entire link you want to share as [www.x.com/offer](http://www.x.com/offer).

Comment: I tried this, but found that even after 3hr since TrendMicro reported the site as "Safe" it still isn't able to be added into a post or facebook message (on website)